# Can I pass a preprocessor definition to the resource compiler through the command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, c-preprocessor, rc

I'm currently trying to switch between a few different default icons in a Visual C++ *.rc* file using `#ifdef` tags.

The builds switching the #define value are being created through the command line using MSBuild.

The difficulty I have been running into is that using [Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010), in order to pass a preprocessor definition to the resource compiler you must define it in the project settings (*Config Properties* → *Resources* → *General*).

This makes it difficult to use an `#ifdef` tag, because using this method it will always be defined in the resource compiler.

I would love to define it to a value, so that I might use a preprocessor `#if SOMEVALUE == 4` might work, but I cannot seem to find a way to pass a Preprocessor definition + value to MSBuild via the command line.

Is there a way to pass a preprocessor definition directly through to the resource compiler or a way to define a value for a preprocessor definition via the command line for MSBuild?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this can be done.

Try using environment variables to pass values into your build process.

In your project properties add ;$(CMDLINE_DEFINES) to the end of your resource preprocessor definitions. (Be sure to pick the right configuration.)

Then when you use MSBuild from the command line type (or add to a batch file)...

```
cd C:\Projects\SomeProject
set CMDLINE_DEFINES=SOMETEST=42
MSBuild SomeProject.vcproj
```

A batch file may look like:

```
@echo off
SET CMDLINE_DEFINES=%1
MSBUILD SomeProject.vcproj
```

Using this batch file, whatever you pass on the command line will be passed on to the build process as your preprocessor macro(s).

Answer (score 2):

> The difficulty I have been running into is that using Visual Studio 2010, in order to pass a preprocessor definition to the resource compiler you must define it in the project settings (Config Properties -> Resources -> General).

You got the hard part.  Just enter the define as `TESTAPPLE=15` and it will effectively `#define TESTAPPLE 15` for the entire project.

Comment: Unfortunately #define values that are passed to project compiler don't get passed down to the Resource compiler.  I.e., /D "TESTAPPLE=15" in when compiling the project sets TESTAPPLE to a value of 15.  In the Resource Compiler, however, TESTAPPLE is just defined, but doesn't have a value of 15.

Comment: huh, guess I haven't played with the resource compiler enough.  http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/042093.html implies that it works `/d "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\""`, but not an authoritive source.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342492/msbuild-c-command-line-can-pass-defines), with the additional step of setting up ResourceCompile options, i.e., edit your project file in a text editor to include elements like this:

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>/DERROR_LOG_LEVEL=5 %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </ClCompile>
    <ResourceCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>/DERROR_LOG_LEVEL=5 %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </ResourceCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the following steps work with me:

1. Pass the variable = underlying value in `msbuild` command line using `/p`, e.g.

   ```
   msbuild my_solution.sln /p:ENVSOMEVALUE="4"
   ```
2. In the project file `my_proj.vcxproj`, define the variable as a preprocessor definition for the resource compiler, and assign it to the  variable passed from `msbuild`, e.g. add the following section inside `<Project></Project>`:

   ```xml
     <ItemDefinitionGroup>
       <ResourceCompile>
         <PreprocessorDefinitions>
           SOMEVALUE=$(ENVSOMEVALUE);
           %(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       </ResourceCompile>
     </ItemDefinitionGroup>
   ```
3. in the `.rc` file, use the code the way you like:

   ```
   #if SOMEVALUE == 4
   ```

   You might need to set a default value for the definition if not passed from `msbuild` (e.g., building from the Visual Studio IDE), in this case you might use the condition *manually* in the project file, e.g.,

   ```xml
     <ItemDefinitionGroup  Condition="'$(ENVSOMEVALUE)'!=''">
       <ResourceCompile>
         <PreprocessorDefinitions>
           SOMEVALUE=$(ENVSOMEVALUE);
           %(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       </ResourceCompile>
     </ItemDefinitionGroup>
     <ItemDefinitionGroup  Condition="'$(ENVSOMEVALUE)'==''">
       <ResourceCompile>
         <PreprocessorDefinitions>
           SOMEVALUE=1; <!-- Default Value -->
           %(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
       </ResourceCompile>
     </ItemDefinitionGroup>
   ```

Comment: Have you tried assigning the variable directly - `msbuild my_solution.sln /p:SOMEVALUE=4`?