# MSBuild C++ - command line - can pass defines?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to convert something like this:

```
#define ERROR_LOG_LEVEL 5
```

Into something that msbuild via command line will pass to its projects?

```
msbuild.exe {???}ERROR_LOG_LEVEL=5 target
```

I've read the responses to similar questions, and it looks like the answer is **no**, just want to double-check in case some genius has found a workaround.

Comment: I should add: is there a way to do the above **without** modifying the project or solution file?

Comment: The answer is **Yes** after all, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17446623/128384

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set PreProcessorDefinitions as a task propery for the msbuild task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros may be defined by passing [the `/D` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) to the compiler.  You can specify the `/D` option from MSBuild using the `AdditionalOptions` of `ClCompile`:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>/DERROR_LOG_LEVEL=5 %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

If you want to be able to pass the value for the macro via a call to msbuild.exe, you can easily do that too:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(ErrorLogLevel)' != ''">
    <ClCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>/DERROR_LOG_LEVEL=$(ErrorLogLevel) %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

with msbuild.exe invoked as:

```
msbuild /p:ErrorLogLevel=5 MyProject.vcxproj
```

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the project file to propagate the value of the MSBuild property `$(ErrorLogLevel)` to the C++ macro `ERROR_LOG_LEVEL` passed to the compiler via the `/D` option.  But, you do not need to use the IDE:  you can edit project files and targets/props files in any text editor of your choosing.

Comment: Thank you. Does the method: `msbuild /p:ErrorLogLevel=5 MyProject.vcxproj` require opening the project in MSVC, or any kind of modification to the MyProject.vcxproj file?

Comment: Okay. I don't have the option to edit the proj file. Read only.

Comment: You can create your own project file that includes the read only project file and specifies the additional options, assuming the read only project file does not do anything horrible like reset ClCompile.AdditionalOptions.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted, but it appears that the answer for my specific case is basically **no**. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry just to confirm: isn't there a way to pass a pre-processor definition from the command line without changing the project file? Something to say ```msbuild /p:ERROR_LOG_LEVEL=5 MyProject.vcxproj```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141429/how-to-set-preprocessordefinitions-as-a-task-propery-for-the-msbuild-task/), but I copy it for another answer. You need to define a user-defined macro in a PropertySheet. Then create a Preprocessor which refers to the user-defined macro. You can now use the new preprocessor value in your code. Finally, for the build, you can change the value of user-defined macro with `/p` flag.
In here I defined a user-defined value like `mymacro` and a preprocessor value like `VAL`.
Now you can simply compile the project with `/p:mymacro="\"some thing new\""`.

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << VAL << std::endl;

    getchar();
}
```

`yourproject.vcxproj`:

```
<ClCompile>
  ...
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>VAL=$(mymacro);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ClCompile>
```

`msbuild yourproject.vcxproj /p:mymacro="\"some thing new\""`