# MSBuild C++ - command line - Can I pass string type defines?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to specify a string parameter from MSBuild commandline.

I define a string type macro in c++ project like:

```
#define MYSTRING "hoge"
```

`MYSTRING` is assigned to a CString variable like:

```
CString str = MYSTRING;
```

And I want to pass this macro parameter via msbuild command line instead defining it on code.

I refered to this similar question,
[MSBuild C++ - command line - can pass defines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342492/msbuild-c-command-line-can-pass-defines)
I added the parameter with /D option in the AdditionalOptions of ClCompile:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
        <AdditionalOptions>/D MYSTRING=$(MyString) %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

And then, with msbuild.exe invoked as:

```
msbuild /p:MyString="hoge" MyProject.vcxproj
```

But the error occured on line `CString str = MYSTRING;`:

```
error C2065: 'hoge': undeclared identifier
```

Do you know why this kind of error occurs ?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You forgot the double quotes around the macro expansion to make it a string.

Comment: Oh, and remember that you probably have to escape the quotes, or the command line shell will remove them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I tried the same things as you mentioned but it didnt worked. 
Instead, I resolved this problem by doing like this:
```#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)```
```CString str = STRINGIZE(MYSTRING)```

Comment: You're saying that `/D MYSTRING="$(MyString)"` didn't work? Or perhaps `/D MYSTRING=""$(MyString)""` (or similar)? How about `/p:MyString=""hoge""`?